# d3 multiple graph not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web

I am having problem when generating 15 line-chars from 15 .csv files by using a for loop. Instead of locating each graph in a different div, 15 graphs all overlapped in the last div.

Thank you in advance.

```js
for (var i = 0; i<15; i++) { 

 var svg = d3.select("#graph_"+i)
 .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv(folder.toString()+"/"+i+".csv", function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
 });

 // Scale the range of the data
 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

 // Add the valueline path.
 svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

 // Add the X Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 // Add the Y Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

});

 }
```

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var` in the for loop and tell us if the problem persists.

Comment: Same issue. They all squeeze in the last div.

Comment: Ok. So, in that case, we need to see the code outside the for loop, and your HTML as well. Try to create a fiddle/plunker/whatever, it's easier and faster to debug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/paul841029/3bq6jy4x/#

Comment: Here is *exactly* your code, with some fake data (I'm drawing only 5 divs), and it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/37h22zez/ The only change I made was moving the divs to inside the `<body>` (they were outside).

Comment: Sorry, after moving the <div> to inside <body>, the same problem occurred. One difference I see is that the way we load the data.

Comment: But that doesn't matter. I put the data in a pre element because I cannot load CSV files in a fiddle (I mean, one can, but not the CSV files in **your** computer). The problem must be somewhere else. Do you see the **same** chart 15 times, or 15 different charts in the same div?

Comment: 0~13 are all blank divs. Different charts all overlap in the 14 div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a classic `async` race condition.  Think about your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i<15; i++) { 
  var svg = d3.select("#graph_"+i) 

  ... 

  d3.csv(folder.toString()+"/"+i+".csv", function(error, data) {

  ...
```

`d3.csv` is **async**; when it completes it fires it's callback.   By the time the first `d3.csv` finishes, your **for loop has already completed** and your `svg` variable is holding a reference to your last div.

The easiest way to fix your problem is with a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i<15; i++) {    

  // closure around svg to keep the proper one in scope
  (function() {

    var svg = d3.select("#graph_"+i);

    ...

    d3.csv(folder.toString()+"/"+i+".csv", function(error, data){

      // svg is now what you are looking for

      ...
    })

  })();

}
```

Here's a [quick demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyfjjDfDgHeHm0B0mabE?p=preview) of this approach.

Stuff like this is why I love JavaScript!